# Where do commas go in "My sunshine she has spared my soul" and "She my sunshine has spared my soul"?

Tags: commas

Where should I put commas in these sentences?

- My sunshine (1) she (2) has spared my soul.
- She (1) my sunshine (2) has spared my soul.

A) Only at (1), B) at both (1) and (2), or C) at neither?

Answer (score 1):

This is not idiomatic conversational speech but literary.

**My sunshine, she has spared my soul.**

The opening phrase "My sunshine" could be understood as supplemental to or apposite "she", with inversion.